# replace each column of pandas dataframe with each value of array

Tags: python, pandas

df is like this,

```
     A    B    C
0  NaN  150 -150
1  100  NaN  150
2 -100 -150  NaN
3 -100 -150  NaN
4  NaN  150  150
5  100  NaN -150
```

Another array is array([1, 2, 3])

I want to replace non-null value in each column with each value in array, and the result will be,

```
      A     B     C
0   NaN   2     3
1   1     NaN   3
2   1     2     NaN
3   1     2     NaN
4   NaN   2     3
5   1     NaN   3
```

How can I achieve this in a **simple** way? I write something like,

```
df[df.notnull()] = np.array([1,2,3])
df[df.notnull()].loc[:,] = np.array([1,2,3])
```

but all cannot work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
>>> (df * 0 + 1) * arr
    A   B   C
0 NaN   2   3
1   1 NaN   3
2   1   2 NaN
3   1   2 NaN
4 NaN   2   3
5   1 NaN   3
```